# for concatenation adding extra commas

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

I am trying to concat authors names, when there is more than one author in a article but for some reason its adding extra commas. This is the code im using:

```
        $get_coauthors = get_coauthors();
    $count = count( $get_coauthors );
    if ( $count > 1 ) {
        for ( $i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++ ) {
            $name .= $get_coauthors[ $i ]->data->display_name . ' ,';
        }
    } else {
        $name = $get_coauthors[0]->data->display_name;
    }
    error_log(print_r($name,true));
```

And my print_r is returning `user1 ,user2 , ,`

Any ideia why?

Comment: Please post the result of `print_r($get_coauthors)`

Comment: Impossible to say for sure without seeing your data, but I'm going to guess one of the authors named is empty.

Comment: Your loop is larger than your array and runnning onto an occurance that does not exist `for ( $i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++ ) {` amend it to `for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {` **Set `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`** and you will see your errors reported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the `count()` or the `if` statement. This might be simpler:

```
//If you already have a $name
$names[] = $name;

foreach(get_coauthors() as $author) {
    $names[] = $author->data->display_name;
}
$names = implode(', ', $names);
```

To remove any empties:

```
$names = implode(', ', array_filter($names));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `rtrim()` to remove last , from your name list.

something like

```
$srting = 'a,b,c,d,e,';
$result_output = rtrim($srting);
echo $result_output;
```

then output : `a,b,c,d,e`

so your code will be

```
$names = '';
foreach(get_coauthors() as $author) {
    $names .= $author->data->display_name. ' ,';
}
$result = rtrim($names,",");
```

or get all name in array then just implode it then you will get result as like user1, users2 etc

```
$names = array();
foreach(get_coauthors() as $author) {
    $names = $author->data->display_name;
}
$names = implode(', ', $names);
```

for more help about array implode

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php